# making cascading dropdown using jquery,php and mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

am trying to make a cascading dropdown, i want when a user select region then city dropdown is populated accordingly..

**JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#region').change(function() {
        var region = $(this).val();
        $.post('get_region.php', {
            region: region
        }, function(data) {
            $('#district_div').html(data);
        });
    });
```

**PHP**:

```
<?php
require_once('../db/connect.php');

$region=$_POST['region'];

$q=mysql_query("select name from city where region='$region'");

$row=mysql_fetch_array($q);
echo $row['name']; 
?>
```

HTML**strong text**

```
 <div class="controls">

                       <select class="bootstrap-select" name="region" id="region">
                                          <option value="">Choose</option>
                                      //from database
                                          <?php echo $region_result; ?>

           </select>
  </div>

                       <select class="bootstrap-select" name="district" id="district" >

                             <div id='district_div'></div>         

          </select>
```

Comment: What's your question? Also, seems like you're missing `})` in js code

Comment: So your are not retrieving data?

Comment: my question is  i dropdown is not populated onchage and where do i miss this  ????

Comment: am retrieving from mysql as u can see in ma php @RicardoGonzales

Comment: Is the element calling the function on change at least?

Comment: yap it does so on change

Comment: why is the `<div id='district_div'></div>` in the `<select>`

Answer (score 1):

```
-for JS it should be like this-

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#region').change(function() {
        var region = $(this).val();
        $.post('get_region.php', {
            region: region
        }, function(data) {
            $('#district').html(data); // I change this part
        });
    });


-for php-

<?php
require_once('../db/connect.php');

$region=$_POST['region'];

$q=mysql_query("select name from city where region='$region'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
   echo "<option>".$row['name']."</option>";
}

?>


-for the html

<div class="controls">
   <select class="bootstrap-select" name="region" id="region">
      <option value="">Choose</option>
      //from database
      <?php echo $region_result; ?>
    </select>

     <select class="bootstrap-select" name="district" id="district" >

     </select>     <!--you don't need to put a div in the select tag-->
</div>
```

Comment: what part of the code you didn't understand.?

as you can see, I just edit the code posted.

Comment: Just some basic understanding of what you have modified... Would help make your answer better...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write plain text inside a select box. Try to write in HTML format:

```
<option>name</option>
```

In your JS, replace the line:

```
$('#district_div').html(data);
```

With:

```
$('#district').html(data);
```

Delete the DIV with id "district_div". You cannot have a DIV inside a SELECT. In PHP, the last line is:

```
echo "<option>$row[name]</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you mis some pieces

```
// will echo the name value of one row
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($q);
    echo $row['name'];
```

try

```
$results = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
$results[] = '<option>.'$row['name'].'</option>';
}
$optionString= implode(' ', $results);
echo $optionsString;
```

Comment: i changed, but nothn goes on onchange

Comment: can you post the html of the dropdown